# Mean of a column I filtered using outlier parameters

Tags: r

I am working on a function which basically filters out rows based on two outliers in a column. I am passing in the column name, the lower outlier and the upper outlier. Even though I got the table filtering to work in a somewhat ugly way (suggestions to do it in one line appreciated), I am having trouble returning the mean of that particular column afterwards. I tried using `get()`, as the column name is a string, but get an error instead. I also had a look at `colMeans()` but could not make it work.

```
findMean <- function(colname, outlier_lower, outlier_upper) {
  initial.data <- survey %>%
    filter_(paste0(colname, "<", outlier_upper))
  filtered.data <- initial.data %>%
    filter_(paste0(colname, ">=", outlier_lower))
  mena <- mean(get(filtered.data$colname))
  return(mean)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got it to work.

```
findMean <- function(colname, outlier_lower, outlier_upper) {
  initial.data <- survey %>%
    filter_(paste0(colname, "<", outlier_upper))
  filtered.data <- initial.data %>%
    filter_(paste0(colname, ">=", outlier_lower)) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(get(colname)))

  return(filtered.data$mean)
}
```